# MVC3: unable to return Login validation error messages to Index.cshtml with Login PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, authentication, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am new to MVC (with 2 years in WebForms).  I am trying to implement Login using PartialView in my Index.cshtml as follow:

```
@Html.Action("LogOnPartial")
```

If the username or password is incorrect, the called method will reach this line as expected:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
```

Because it is a partial view, I pass the model back to the Index.cshtml as follow in order to show the 'incorrect' entries:

```
// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
return View("Index", model);
```

Then Index.cshtml will then call @Html.Action("LogOnPartial"), which in turn trigger this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOnPartial(LogOnModel model)
{
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

After rendering, the 'incorrect' entries will remain in the textbox as expected, but the above error message "The user name or password provided is incorrect." is not displayed.  I guess the error messages are not passed in the above method.

How can I show the error message when returning from the partial view?

Thanks.

---

Thanks Marks, your suggestion is very helpful.  Originally I already included @Html.ValidationSummary() in the end of my LogOnPartial.cshtml but somehow the error message didn't show up in the Index.cshtml.  Now I moved the @Html.ValidationSummary() to Index.cshtml as follows:

```
@Html.Action("LogOnPartial")
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
```

and now it works ok and I can see the login error message.

However, now I have another problem.  There are two partial views in my Index.cshtml.  One is for the LogOnPartial.cshtml and the other is for SignUpPartial.cshtml (you may want to take a look at www.iguardpayroll.com, which is written in WebForms, and you will see there are two boxes in the left column: one is for Login and the other is for Sign Up).

In additional to adding the @Html.ValidationSummary() right underneath the @Html.Action("LogOnPartial"), I also need to add it under the @Html.Action("SignUpPartial") in order to show the error message caused by the signup process (e.g. email already exists!).  However, if I do that the same LogOn error message will appear twice under both the LogOn part and the SignUp part.

```
   <div>
      @Html.Action("LogOnPartial")
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    </div>
    <div>
      @Html.Action("SignUpPartial")
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Sign Up was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")   
    </div>
```

How can I tell the first @Html.ValidationSummary() only shows the error message related to LogOnPartial, and the 2nd @Html.ValidationSummary() only shows the Sign Up error message?

Comment: Where the error message is not getting displayed? in validation summary?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` inside the form to display the model validation errors.

Ex.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary()
   .. fields
}
```